# Python Plotly Share Both Axes

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to use Plotly to have fully linked axes (e.g. all plots should move in both directions when any plot is moved). Is this possible? When I try to link more than one axes I get overlapping plots - which makes sense based on the way linked panning get implemented in Plotly.

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2,shared_xaxes=True,shared_yaxes=True)


fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,1,2]), 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[5,6,7], y=[2,1,2]), 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[8,9,10], y=[2,1,2]), 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[11,12,13], y=[2,1,2]), 2, 2)

fig['data'][1]['xaxis'] = 'x1'
py.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Check out the following link: [link](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/)